# SQL Query to retreive records

Tags: mysql

Information
I have three database tables

1. ProductInfo with fields :**Name** , **invemtoryid**, **hassizes**
2. SizeInfo table with fields:  **Sizeid**, **inventoryid** , **sizedesc**
3. OrdersInfo table with fields **orderid**, **inventoryid**, **sizeid**, **quantityordered**

The sizeinfo table does not have a record for the product which does not have any sizes
The orderinfo has a null in the column of size id if a product which does not have any sizes is ordered

I am trying to retrive information about all the products which were included in the order. I am able to get the product with sizes without any problem but when getting the products with sizes is giving me issues.

Below is the query I have so far

```
select p.ProductName, o.InventoryId, s.sizedesc, o.OrderQuantity 
from OrdersInfo o, ProductInfo p, ProductSizeInfo s 
where OrderId = 1 
and p.inventoryid = o.inventoryid 
and s.sizeid= o.sizeid
```

Any idea what am I missing. I have already tried all kinds of JOINS but did not get what I am expecting

Comment: Please add your data set and wished result set

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Which kinds of `JOIN`s have you tried to use and why doesn't that work?

Comment: you are using implicit joins and this is why you don't get the expected results. Use the explicit joins and you will get what you want

Comment: @LelioFaieta Any examples of explicit joins?

Comment: @NicoHaase Tried INNER JOIN and OUTER JOIN

Comment: @LearningPhase: Example of explicit JOIN: from OrdersInfo o JOIN ProductInfo p ON o.inventoryid = p.inventoryid (and so on...)